# Ingesting data to kusto database using c#

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am using kusto .net SDK to write to kusto database using c#.. I am able to create the table as I please, but I wish to be able to write some rows to the database and populate the columns "a" and "b".. couldn't find an easy way to do this online..

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var KustoClusterConnectionString = $"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";            
        var KustoDbName = "userGroup";            
        var AppId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var TenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        
        var kcsb = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(KustoClusterConnectionString)
        {
            InitialCatalog = KustoDbName,
            FederatedSecurity = true,
            ApplicationClientId = AppId,
            ApplicationKey = clientSecret,
            Authority = TenantId
        };                     

        var tableName = "userGroup";  
        using (var kustoClient = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslAdminProvider(kcsb))
        {
            var command =
                CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableCreateCommand(
                    tableName,
                    new[]
                    {
            //Tuple.Create("TimeStamp", "System.DateTime"),
            Tuple.Create("a", "System.String"),
            Tuple.Create("b", "System.String"),

                    });

            kustoClient.ExecuteControlCommand(KustoDbName, command);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

there are several code samples in this repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-samples-dotnet

specifically - this project/file: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-samples-dotnet/blob/master/client/HowToDataIngestion/Program.cs

Comment: Yes, I did see this, but I don't wish to do it from a json file, I just want to have 2 variables(strings) and have a simple code to be able to ingest into the table..

Comment: ingesting a few records at a time isn't recommended in Production scenarios.
if you still want to do so, you can invoke the `.ingest inline` control command, using the `ExecuteControlCommand` method you're already calling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-inline. to generate the command's text, you can use `CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableIngestPushCommand(...)`, that's included in the client library

Comment: Yes, however, CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableIngestPushCommand() still asks for string csvData... do you have an example that formats this.../calls this function?

Comment: alternatively, you can create the string on your own, e.g. ```var value1 = "hello"; var value2 = "world"; var tableName = "mytable"; var cmd = $".ingest inline into table {tableName} <| {value1},{value2}```